# Transistor identification

Tags: transistors

I have had a battery power bank from anker (powercore 20100mah) for some time now and it stopped working. Upon opening the case i saw a blown up transistor and i am having trouble identifying it. It says X04V 1A. On the circuit board where the part sits it says Q4. Figured I might change it and go from there because I don't want to scrap a power bank with some life in the 18650 cells. 
This is the picture of the part https://drive.google.com/file/d/1awlKVwYiXqPgU9bCaWnTlCcFwTszKaeU/view?usp=drivesdk
To what I can understand this is an LDO regulator. Problem is i don't know the specs! Could you please help find an alternative to it? Thank you!

Comment: Photo of it please!

Comment: @winny hey! Thanks for input.  please see picture in answer section. On the part it says X 04V and horizontally 1A

Comment: The picture of the part needs permission.

Comment: There's a photo upload button on the editor toolbar.

Comment: @ValentinVirban Report back if you got any problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could you please help find an alternative to it?

Without knowing the complete schematic, it's impossible to find an alternative for it, as different component will have different characteristics and may affect the system greatly. It's better to just stick with the known one you provided before.

---

> I am having trouble identifying it

I don't know if you have read [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/334128/how-do-i-identify-smd-components-or-how-do-i-identify-any-component/) or not, but if you haven't, it may have some useful tips for you.

---

## Lets find it!

Sometimes, looking on online store may work if its stock is available. Otherwise, the result may be excluded from its search menu. Thus, the google cache may be your best friend. Such as using these keyword:

```
X04V site:aliexpress.com 
XO4V site:aliexpress.com
```

Also, online forums or non-English sites may also help you, I've found on google this Chinese store [here](http://product.dzsc.com/product/991757-20140905075105493.html) and I've found its discussion [here](http://budgetlightforum.com/node/33991).

It's true that finding SMD Marking can be a labyrinth adventures.
So try to look at [SMD Marking database](https://www.google.com/search?q=SMD%20marking) on the internet first.

And it's common for several attempts to be failed. I've failed to find it on here [here](http://caxapa.ru/thumbs/588912/smd-codes.pdf) and [here](http://chip.tomsk.ru/chip/chipdoc.nsf/vc1!readform&view=smd&cat=X&start=1&count=500). Those packages listed are not SOT23 from your picture. Fortunately, I've found it [here](http://www.s-manuals.com/smd/x0) with only one correct SOT23 package.

By verifying on the manufacture Alpha & Omega Semiconductor Inc. (AOS) product page, [here](http://www.aosmd.com/products/mosfets/single/AO3400A).

This is screenshot from Marking pdf that the company provide.

[image]

It's seems legit that this X04V 1A is AO3400A N-Channel MOSFET 30V 5.7A@Vgs=10V.

Reasons:

- The IC on your picture package is SOT-23
- X indicates its product type.
  If you take a look on A03400 (notice without "A" letter at the end) product page [here](http://www.aosmd.com/products/mosfets/single/AO3400) on its datasheet. There are negligible differences on its spec, only \$\mathrm{R_{DS(ON)}}\$ and \$\mathrm{I_D}\$. And it's only differs by one significant figure. Also the marking of its product is "A" and not "X". I don't know in the first place why AOS build those two almost identical IC with both Full Production status.
- 0 indicates it's AO3400A or AO3400AL
- AO3400AL is the Lead-Free version. Although its not stated in the datasheet, but from other Alpha Omega Semiconductor datasheets such as [here](https://xdevs.com/doc/_Datasheets/ALPHA_OMEGA/ao3401l.pdf), I can see the pattern and conclude that it's the Lead-Free version. Read more about Lead-Free from other Q&A on this site [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13913/when-does-lead-free-matter) or [here](http://eesemi.com/pbfree.htm).
- 4 indicates the Week code
- V indicates the assembly location code (probably private internal information)
- 1A indicates the assembly lot code (probably private internal information)
- At first, it may makes sense to think that 1A is the current rating of a MOSFET or linear regulator. But I highly doubt it in this case, because of the previous clues.

  > https://eesemi.com/assyglossary.htm 
  >   **lot** - a group of similarly-processed semiconductor devices, usually from the same production run, treated as a homogeneous population
  >
  > https://www.svmi.com/glossary-terms-semiconductor/ 
  >   **Lot**: Wafers of similar sizes and characteristics placed together in a shipment.

---

## Where to buy it?

You may search on your local reputable supplier, or you can search it on AliExpress for cheap [here](https://www.aliexpress.com/w/wholesale-AO3400A.html?&SortType=price_asc), but I won't guarantee that it is counterfeit or not. Also you may notice at AliExpress the marking will vary such as A09T, it's the one without letter A before. For 3400 marking, it's from different manufacture, [CYStech Electronics Corp](https://en.cystekec.com/index_down.php?sele=DynPID&iyes=877&tgdyn=18) from Taiwan which is [MTN3400N3](http://ftp01.cystekec.com/MTN3400N3.pdf), which also has nearly identical spec. By the way, A0XX and 3400 are nearly identical with X0XX so you can also buy those instead.

Warning! [A1XX, X1XX,](http://www.aosmd.com/search?q=3401) and [3401](http://ftp01.cystekec.com/MTP3401N3.pdf) are P-Channel MOSFET, make sure you do not buy that.

For reputable online supplier I'm unable it to find on [Farnell](https://www.newark.com/search?st=AO3400A) and Mouser doesn't seems to supply from AOS ([Mouser supplier page](https://www.mouser.com/supplierpage/)). But I found it on Digi-Key [here](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=785-1000-1-ND) for 0.45 USD ([without shipping rates](https://www.digikey.com/classic/ordering/internatlshiprates.aspx)).

I can only find AO3400A on Digi-Key (which is available in stock) and unable to find it for the other two before.

---

## Conclusions

You could imagine we could find nearly three identical SMD component from thorough searching process with such distinct marking information. That's why I stated earlier, this could be labyrinth adventures. I hope it will help you and someone else reading this in the future.

I recommend you to buy its replacement from the Digi-Key that I've linked before or your local reputable supplier.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found it in stock at digikey uk. Shoul be here in a few days.